# Read and write an excel file from Azure Blob Storage without downloading it to local file in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using **azure-storage** dependency to **create a reference of azure directory** then after downloading the file in local system I am able to read and write using **poi-ooxml library** then again uploading the same file in azure storage.

**I just want to remove this local downloading thing. Is there any way to read and write the excel file without downloading it in local.**

Dependencies Used.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code

```
try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlobDirectory downloadDirectory = container.getDirectoryReference(dowloadDirectoryName);

        for(ListBlobItem blobItem: downloadDirectory.listBlobs()) {

            if(blobItem instanceof CloudBlockBlob) {

                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blobItem;
                File inputFile = new File(cloudBlob.getName());
                cloudBlob.downloadToFile(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
                
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
                Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream); 
                /*Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputFile);*/
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);       
                log.info("Cell No 0 : "+sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                    Cell reasonLabel = sheet.getRow(i).createCell(2);
                    reasonLabel.setCellValue("Added one cell");
                }
                
                File outputFile = new File(cloudBlob.getName().split("\\.")[0]+"01.xls");
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                workbook.write(outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
                workbook.close();
                
                CloudBlobDirectory uploadDirectory =  container.getDirectoryReference(uploadDirectoryName);
                CloudBlockBlob uploadBlob = uploadDirectory.getBlockBlobReference(outputFile.getName());
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
                uploadBlob.upload(fileInputStream, outputFile.getTotalSpace());
                fileInputStream.close();
                outputFile.delete();
                
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: Maybe you could look into a lambda or whatever Microsoft calls that?  Probably best to check the azure api docs.

Comment: Apache POI will work quite happily with an `InputStream` and `OutputStream` just as with a `File` - you just need to find a library for your azure storage system that provides those for blobs

Comment: FYI Azure Blob Storage doesn't have the concept of *directories* unless you're accessing an File Share (or using ADLS).

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added the code in question

Comment: @Gagravarr I am using the same InputStream and OutputStream but still one new file is getting downloaded each time in local directory which I have to delete again and again

Comment: CloudBlockBlob has a “downloadToStream” method. Please try to use that instead of “downloadToFile”. You can use that stream to create your Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

This is my soultion for reading a file from Azure blob with NPOI

```
foreach (var blob in blobContainer.GetBlobs())
        {
            var blobClient = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);

            using MemoryStream memStream = new();
            blobClient.DownloadTo(memStream);
            memStream.Position = 0;
            var wb = new XSSFWorkbook(memStream);
            sheetName = wb.GetSheetAt(0).SheetName;
            sheet = (XSSFSheet)wb.GetSheet(sheetName);
}
```